# Ipython Notebook not printing type() in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

This is a pretty bizarre bug:

The following code:

```
a = 'string1'
b = 'string2'

test_dict = {'col1':{a:type(a), b:type(b)},'col2':{a:type(a), b:type(b)}}
pd.DataFrame(test_dict)
```

In a normal ipython console yields the following as expected:

```
                col1          col2
string1  <type 'str'>  <type 'str'>
string2  <type 'str'>  <type 'str'>
```

However in the ipython notebook, the cells where the type should be displayed is empty:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that if you do a View->Source in your browser you will see the expected <type ...>. What's happening is that the browser thought this was an HTML tag, didn't recognize it, and simply threw it out.

Note: if I had not typed `&amp;lt;type ...>` in this answer, the same thing would have happened to my answer.

Comment: I was able to solve by converting to a string and reg ex'ing everything but the actual data type out...not pretty but it works and it's more compact then printing the whole <type 'str'> nonsense

Comment: This is not a bug in IPython, it is a bug in pandas - pandas is telling IPython that it already has an HTML repr, which IPython trusts is properly escaped, but it is not.  Opened as pandas [Issue 2617](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2617).

Answer (score 3):

A workaround is to print the dataframe, which makes it play better with the ipython notebook:

```
In [144]: print pd.DataFrame(test_dict)

                 col1          col2
string1  <type 'str'>  <type 'str'>
string2  <type 'str'>  <type 'str'>
```

I find the lines in the HTML tables distracting, so this workaround is my default.